# Recurrence Relationship Questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursion

Consider the recurrence defined by:

$$G_0 = 0\\
G_n = G_{n-1} + 2n - 1$$

**Determine what Gn is for several values of n to determine a formula for Gn.**

1. $2n$
2. $n$
3. $2n-1$
4. $n^2$

*I believe this one is 2n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cheat, and use generating functions. Define $G(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} G_n z^n$. Write the recurrence so there aren't subtractions in indices:
$$
G_{n + 1} = G_n + 2 n + 1
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} G_{n + 1} z^n &= \frac{G(z) - G_0}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n           &= \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n         &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z}
                              = \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align}
This gives:
$$
\frac{G(z)}{z} = G(z) + 2 \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2} + \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Solving for $G(z)$:
$$
G(z) = \frac{z + z^2}{1 - 3 z + 3 z^2 - z^3}
     = \frac{1}{1 - z}
         - 3 \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
         + 2 \frac{1}{(1 - z)^3}
$$
Using the generalized binomial theorem:
\begin{align}
G_n &= \binom{-1}{n} (-1)^n - 3 \binom{-2}{n} (-1)^n + 2 \binom{-3}{n} (-1)^n \\
    &= \binom{n + 1 - 1}{1 - 1}
         - 3 \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1}
         + 2 \binom{n + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} \\
    &= 1 - 3 \frac{n + 1}{1!} + 2 \frac{(n + 2)(n + 1)}{2!} \\
    &= n^2
\end{align}

Comment: Killing a fly with a sledge hammer! :P  You forgot a factor of $z$ in the middle equality of $\sum_{n \geq 0} n z^n$.

Comment: @SpamIAm, thanks, fixed.

Comment: Wrong metaphor! It is "cracking a peanut with a sledge hammer".

Comment: @martycohen According to [this link](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut.html), the fly predates the nut.

Comment: @vonbrand I don't think someone who comes with this kind of a question (and guess the answer wrong) can comprehend a solution like yours, which uses heavy machinery. You may use telescoping sums to solve the problem, it's just adding and subtracting. Personally, I hardly followed your argument.

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

[image]

Hopefully this will help you solve the question.

Otherwise you can just calculate the first 3-4 $G_n$ and see to which of the proposed solutions it corresponds :
\begin{eqnarray*}
G_0 &=& 0\\
G_1 &=& G_0 + 2\cdot1 - 1 \qquad n = 1 \text{ here}\\
&=& 0 + 2 - 1\\
&=& 1\\
G_2 &=& G_1 + 2\cdot2 - 1 \qquad n = 2 \text{ here}\\
&=&...
\end{eqnarray*}

Now keep on going.